# rails main layout missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, layout, view

I'm using the latest version of ruby and ROR.
I have placed some code in the `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb file`. Let's say something like this:

```
<html>
<head><title>ABC</title></head>
<body>
  <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm having trouble getting the layout to show in my Home page (the only page I have atm).
The Home page is a .html.erb file too, and it contains basic html and rails commands. I have created the controller for it like so:

```
class HomeController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  def index
    #nothing yet
  end
end
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HomeController is inheriting from ActionController::Base. Make it inherit from ApplicationController. That might help

Change

```
 class HomeController < ActionController::Base
```

to

```
 class HomeController < ApplicationController
```

Comment: tnx. I'll accept the answer in 10 mins. I copyed that code from the application_controller so that's where the error came from.